# Satisfying Child View Model Dependencies

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependencies, ioc-container, master-detail

I'm building a master-detail form. The master view model constructs instances of the details view model. These details view models have several dependencies which need to be satisfied with *new* class instances. (This is because they need service layers that operate in a separate data context from the master vm.)

What would be the best way to fulfill these dependencies?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some Possibilities:

#### Hard-Coded References

The following approach would solve the problem. However, as it introduces hard-coded dependencies, using it is out of the question.

```
// in the master view model
var detailViewModel = new DetailViewModel(new AccountService(), new TransactionService());
```

#### Resolution via IoC Framework

Another option would be for the parent view model to hold a reference to an IoC framework. This approach introduces a master view model dependency on the IoC framewok.

```
// in the master view model
var detailViewModel = new DetailViewModel(resolver.GetNew<IAccountService>(), resolver.GetNew<IAccountService>());
```

#### Factory Func<>s

```
class MasterViewModel {
  public MasterViewModel(Func<Service.IAccountService> accountServiceFactory, Func<Service.ITransactionService> transactionServiceFactory) {
    this.accountServiceFactory = accountServiceFactory;
    this.transactionServiceFactory = transactionServiceFactory;

    // instances for MasterViewModel's internal use
    this.accountService = this.accountServiceFactory();
    this.transactionService = this.transactionServiceFactory():
  }
  public SelectedItem { 
    set {
       selectedItem = value;
       DetailToEdit = new DetailViewModel(selectedItem.Id, accountServiceFactory(), transactionServiceFactory());
    }
    // ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how to implement a Master/Detail scenario with M-V-VM. It uses MEF as IoC Container to satisfy the ViewModel dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the container to construct the detail view:

```
var detailViewModel = container.CreateInstance<DetailViewModel>();
```

The container will resolve the dependencies for IAccountService and ITransactionService.  But you will still have a dependency on the IOC framework (unless you use the [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/)).

Here is how I do it using the CommonServiceLocator:

```
this.accountService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IAccountService>();
this.transactionService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstancey<ITransactionService>();
```